# Load Testing "Excel could not be launched. Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: excel, report, visual-studio-2017, load-testing

After a Load Test Run I click the "Create Excel Report" button and get the error message:

[image]

> Excel could not be launched. Object reference not set to an instance of an object

How does this work?

<sub>Note: Answering my own question to help others in future.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I found a [similar MSDN forum post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3d909cf2-6f67-4f9e-9117-484cd9084cc5/cannot-create-excel-load-test-report-from-vs2010-load-test?forum=vstest) where running as Admin and checking the Loadbehvior was the fix. So I ran [ProcessMonitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) and checked the LoadBehavior and changed it from 10 to 3:

[image]

That ensures the Add-In will be loaded, then the trick is you go to Excel and there is a LoadTest Add-In:

[image]